# Regex to match very occurrence in string

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a string `"Format: Multiple videos Length:20 mins ....Format: Video with Length: 50 mins"` and want to enclose "Format ...mins" part in a tag e.g.

```
"<p>Format: Multiple videos Length:20 mins</p> ....<p>Format: Video with Length: 50 mins</p>"
```

The regex I have in Coldfusion is

```
<cfset str= reReplace(str, "Format:(.*?)Video(.*?)mins", "<p>Format:\1Video\2mins</p>", "ALL")>
```

but I get output as

```
"<p>Format: Multiple videos Length:20 mins ....Format: Video with Length: 50 mins</p>"
```

What is the proper regex to match every occurrence in the string?

Comment: Try `REReplaceNoCase(str, "Format:((?:(?!Format:|Video|mins).)*)Video((?:(?!Format:|mins).)*)mins", "<p>Format:\1Video\2mins</p>", "ALL")` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2aNju/1)).

Comment: That worked thank you so much! Never would have figured that one out by myself :o)

Comment: I feel stupid now coz the only thing missing in my regex was to make it case insensitive. This works ```<cfset str= reReplaceNocase(str, "Format:(.*?)Video(.*?)mins", "<p>Format:\1Video\2mins</p>", "ALL")>```

Comment: No, it would over match.

Comment: Seems to work though See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N91gtL/1)

Comment: Here it is [overmatching](https://regex101.com/r/N91gtL/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
REReplaceNoCase(str, "Format:((?:(?!Format:|Video|mins).)*)Video((?:(?!Format:|mins).)*)mins", "<p>Format:\1Video\2mins</p>", "ALL")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2aNju/1).

*Details*:

- `REReplaceNoCase` - case insensitive regex replace function
- `Format:` - a fixed string
- `((?:(?!Format:|Video|mins).)*)` - Group 1: any text up to the first `Video` that has no `Format:`, `Video` and `mins` substrings
- `Video` - a fixed string
- `((?:(?!Format:|mins).)*)`  - Group 2: any text up to the first `mins` that has no `Format:` and `mins` substrings
- `mins` - a fixed string